# Выдаёт ошибку(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\forer\index.php on line 21)

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$email', 
   '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_master_query($connection, $query);
        if($result){
            $smsg = "Регистрация прошла успешна"
        }
            else{
            $fsmsg = "Ошибка";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
        <h2>Регистрация</h2>
        <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> 
        </div><?php}?>
        <?php if(isset($fsmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fsmsg; ? 
        > </div><?php}?>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У Вас после `$smsg = "Регистрация прошла успешна"` нет точки с запятой.
2. Во втором `<?php if(isset($fsmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fsmsg; ?  > </div><?php}?>` некорректно написан закрывающий тег php

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @QizZz, пожалуйста :) Если ответ помог, поставьте галочку